# mod_rewrite defeated by file names

Tags: macos, apache, mod-rewrite, webserver, osx-mountain-lion

I'm having a strange issue on my Mac OS X (10.8) dev computer.  I configured mod_rewrite to be on and it does seem to work in certain situations.  I have one test rule right now that I'm trying to make work but it just won't, unless I change the rule to do something I don't want.

Here's the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^driver/([0-9]+)$ driver.php?d=$1 [L]
```

Now, if I attempt to call driver/411.  What apache appears to be doing is calling driver.php with no GET parameters and ignoring the .htaccess rules altogether.  I know this to be true because this rule with a hardcoded value also fails:

```
RewriteRule ^driver/([0-9]+)$ driver.php?d=411 [L]
```

However, if I replace the prefix I'm looking for to not match the file name prefix, it works:

```
RewriteRule ^driverz/([0-9]+)$ driver.php?d=$1 [L]
```

Does anyone know how I go about telling apache to not do this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because MultiViews internally redirect to driver.php, before mod_rewrite get's applied. So there will be no GET parameters.

Disable MultiViews by adding the following to your htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

(PS Apache should disable this by default. Who uses MultiViews anyways)